# transient List of Database.Error becomes null in finish

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, stateful

I have a list to to accumulate All dB Errors, I need to use that list in finish. But the transient variable is null in finish.
Here is My class:

```
global class BatchToDoSomething implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.stateful{
    //other variables
    global transient List<Database.Error> dbErrors = new List<Database.Error>();
    global List<Log__c> logs = new List<Log__c>();
    global BatchToDoSomething (Set<Id> ProjIds,STring pbName){
        System.debug('transient in construnctor '+dbErrors);
        System.debug('transient in construnctor logs '+logs);
        //varaible inits;
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('transient in start '+dbErrors);
        System.debug('transient in start logs '+logs);
        String query = 'some query';
        System.debug('query'+query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Finance__c> scope){
        try{
            System.debug('transient in execution '+dbErrors);
            System.debug('transient in execution logs '+logs);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
           //some catch
        }
        
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('transient in finish '+dbErrors);
        System.debug('transient in finsih logs '+logs);
        if (dbErrors!=null && dbErrors.size()>0) {
            LogUtility.creatLogsFromDatabaseErrors('someclass', BC.getJobId(), 'W__c', dbErrors);
        }
        if(logs!=null && logs.size()>0){
            LogUtility.insertLogs(logs);
        }
    }
}
```

The logs are as follows :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Some names are hidden/changed due to confidentiality.
You can not that *dbErrors* get null after sometime but *logs*  is maintained.
Note :

1. dbErrors need to be transient because without it, Serialization error is there
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MebKq.png

Comment: Why have you even declared it `transient`, remove that. Your `Database.stateful{ ` will make sure your state is maintained till finish is called.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE (Salesforce StackExchange). I think you have to go back to design this because `transient` is making the variable not persistent between executions (even with you marking the job as stateful. You may want rethink what you want to store in the log or when, because `Database.Error` are not serializable.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Database.Error is not Serializable hence an exception is through, since we are implementing Stateful

Comment: But why do you need to pass that to finish, insert that in the same `execute` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transient variables are not serialized, and serializing some types of objects throws exceptions because they are not serializable. You'll need to convert the `Database.Error` objects into something you can serialize (e.g. a class that you write).

```
class DatabaseError {
  String message;
  // etc...
}
DatabaseError[] errors = new DatabaseError[0];
// ...
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Finance__c[] scope) {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch(Exception e) {
    errors.add(convertToError(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, did that only. Thankx for answer